# imported project from SVN wont launch in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

Projects in my eclipse local workspace launch and run correctly (Hello World Java project and also Hello World Android project open fine in the emulator).
When I import a project from SVN (the project is the android Hello World app)
and try to run this project I get an error: "Unable to launch" "The selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches".

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: There needs to be more detail about the problematic project.  What kind of project was it?  Was the .project file also stored in SVN?  Were other "dot" files?  *What* were you trying to launch in this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the project -> Right Click -> Run As -> Android Application

Comment: When i right click -> run as -> there are no options. all i see is 'run configuration'

Comment: Does the imported project contain a .project file ?

Comment: i have two projects now in my repository source. one is the android hello world app and other is java hello world. 
take the hello world java project, all i have is my src and bin folders. i have this project in local workspace and it works perfect, when it is imported, it cannot launch

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand. You have your problem with hello world java project or the android one or both ?

Comment: I had a problem with them both not launching but i got it fixed. I was importing the project from the wrong level. i needed to go in one level further in my repository url. thanks for your help though!

Comment: Ah, okay! Great then! Good luck ahead! :)